# Drastic Question Revision

Tags: discussion, edits

I was looking over some old comments of mine, and I saw one that just looked completely irrelevant to the question asked. I was confused, so I looked at the edit history and I found this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22818952/revisions

What do you do when a question is completely re-written and doesn't even relate the previous question asked? Because now all the comments and answers and wrong and off topic appearing.

Is this where I can rollback or flag? I'm not sure.

Comment: This reminds me of the question on Programmers that was rewritten as cleanup to be featured in Ars Technica. The editor accidentally changed the meaning of the question, which lead to a lot of answers only making partial sense, and the question was closed shortly afterward. That put us in the awkward position of keeping the new question and having the answers/comments not make total sense or confusing all of the users coming from Ars Technica.

Comment: I kind of feel bad. The question I linked to went from -6 to -18 because of this meta xD

Comment: @RUJordan, Don't feel bad. It won't make any difference at all.

Comment: @chris it __made__ a difference. The linked question is closed or deleted - probably by reviewers not aware of this discussion on meta and the background of the problem. I suspect it should be rather rolled back as Robert Harvey says.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, I see your point. It wasn't yet deleted when I posted, but yeah, I should have seen that coming.

Comment: Related: *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/)*

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Roll it back to the best version that asks the original question.

The most common reason this happens is that the user is question-banned; since they can't ask any more questions, they just revise one of their old ones and hope the resulting bump causes someone to see their "new" question and answer it.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm glad I wasn't smart enough to think of that when I was Q-Banned a couple years ago lol

Comment: It's funny people are clever when tricking the rules. But not clever when they should play by the rules :).

Comment: @RobertHarvey why aren't question banned users also edit banned?

Comment: @ArtB: Because one of the things we tell them is that they *might* get unbanned if they fix their existing questions.  Look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), under the subheading: "Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!"

Comment: any statistics on how often they succeed at getting unbanned? I wonder if they are likely cause more damage than good at that point.

Comment: How often can a bad post be improved? If a user is bad enough for a question ban, the questions are more than a misunderstanding or bad formatting - they are unhelpable crap.

Comment: @RobertHarvey then why dont we put even own question editing done by Q-Banned person on review queue for reviewing ?

Comment: What should someone do though if they realized they asked a dumb question and there's no way to fix it?