# How to deal with a question that has been completely changed

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-history

I spotted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943163/get-keys-and-values-from-listdictionary) where the user, rather than ask a new question, decided to [rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27943163/revisions) an old one. Should this edit be rolled back and the user informed or just left alone?

The original question had no votes and no comments at all but I still feel it should be a new question.

Edit: The 'new' question now has an answer, does that affect the decision?

Comment: It should be rolled back to the original question.

Comment: I have rolled it back, per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260066/3001761

Comment: Looks like the user [is persisting in this behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28534798/464709). I rolled back the edit and left a comment, if they still persist I will have to escalate to flags.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That one is even a double edit, good idea to check their history.

Comment: Indeed that user appears to have a recurring habit of "recycling" most of their questions. Several times. I just went into a rollback spree, things should be cleaned up now.

Comment: @Deduplicator my bad - those revisions were collapsed and I didn't clock the difference between **Jan** 14 and **Apr** 14, so I assumed that helb's revision was the "last good" point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Drastic Question Revision question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260069/1380867) it should be rollback to the best version that asks the original question. A reason why a user may choose to  Drastic Revise a Question may be that they are and are looking to get out of it.  Please read more at [Drastic Question Revision question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260069/1380867)