# What to do when a new user continuously edits their question?

Tags: discussion, flags, edits

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4858774/hristo-tsonev) is continously updating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421513/why-i-cant-fill-arraylist-in-java-edited/30421546#30421546) with each evolution of their code, making answers obsoletes and making it hard for other users to understand what is happening.

Should we do something about this?

**EDIT:** instead of [this suggested duplicated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066/drastic-question-revision), I'm not facing a problem that happened time ago and I realize now, the question linked is already searching for an answer and user is editing it right now.

Comment: I'm not sure, but in my opinion an edit lock would be in place.

Comment: I'd post a comment telling him not to do that, and why, and what to do instead, and linking to somewhere appropriate in help. Then, if you have the rep, roll back the question to the first revision that someone wrote a useful answer for.

Comment: For "what to do instead", usually that's as simple as just creating a new question, and link them together with the `share` links if they have relevant information for each other. Once I explain this to people, they usually get it. (A couple days ago, one of them said something like, "Does that mean I can get upvotes and accept-credits twice if I do both questions well? Cool!")

Comment: Why is this tagged "review-suspension"? Did you get review-banned because you voted on a review of this question and you chose the right thing to do for the question in one state, but it turned out to be the wrong thing to do because the OP had meanwhile changed it?

Comment: Required reading: [Exit strategies for chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) on Meta.SE.

Comment: @Deduplicator problem on question you linked was old, this one is happening already

Comment: @JordiCastilla: Yes, it's nearly a year old. But nothing changed in that regard...

Comment: @Deduplicator check my edit, hope I explained it better... I didn't meant that... ;)

Comment: Well, it does not matter how you found and recognized those edits. Only that they fundamentally change the question and invalidate answers.

Comment: not really, as suggested in thread by @Jongware we can invite user to chat, for example.... what does not make sense with an old question...

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing is to write a good comment that explains to the user that he shouldn't do this, and why, and what he should do instead. In particular, what he should do instead is almost certainly create a new question, possibly using `share` links between the two, and accept the answer that solved his first problem.

Next, I'm not sure whether this goes with or against policy, but when I see this kind of thing, I roll back the question to the first revision that someone wrote a good answer for (and maybe edit it further from there to improve the question as it stood at that time).

If I didn't have the rep to do that, I don't think I'd flag the question, but I might add a comment or go to the chat room suggesting that someone else do so.