# What to do when a new user delete content their question after It has been answered correctly?

Tags: discussion, edits, flags, post-ban

This user deletes the content of the question after It has been answered correctly, then, I flagged "need of moderator intervention" I requested to ban the user

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417484/transition-markov-matrix-with-numpy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404786/reshape-into-matrix-given-a-file-of-values

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245378/how-to-generate-matrix-from-fasta-files

This case is different to [drastic-question-revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066/drastic-question-revision), It looks like the user uses Stack Overflow as coding service, my question is: did I follow the regular channel when I did flag?

Comment: I rolled them back to the appropriate revision. As you already flagged, I didn't.