# User got their answer, had a new question in comments on answer, deleted their question

Tags: discussion

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315188/unity-progress-bar/44316404) (currently deleted) and when the user had a follow up question that ended up being too complex to answer in the comments I asked him to create a new question as it was out of scope for the question he'd asked and that I had provided a satisfactory answer to the current question.

A moment later (I was still on the question page) it went white and was marked "this question has been deleted."  The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6530636/alex) never even thought about voting up or accepting my answer as correct, despite the fact that it was (I received no notifications about acceptance).

Based on [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295162/what-to-do-when-a-new-user-delete-content-their-question-after-it-has-been-answe) (and related duplicates) this is not appropriate behavior and I'm asking for the question to be undeleted.  The comments could use some cleanup as well as it took quite a bit of back and forth to figure out precisely what the asker was having trouble with (I *almost* threw up my hands in frustration and walked away, but my last attempt to clarify returned the information I'd been trying to extract).

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately, users do that.  If it looks like homework, rep 1 and 'Member for today', it's a risk:(   Sounds like you got a homework and vampirism - a particularly nasty combo.  User needs staking.

Comment: Who do you expect to come across this question and find this solution useful?  I personally can't see how that's going to happen with a question like that.  The user did the site a favor removing a question that's not useful to anyone.

Comment: It is also possible that OP thought that he could ask another question when he deletes his first one, because he got notified that he currently ask any more questions due to the question limit for new users.

Comment: Ah, that might've been the reason. Thanks @Tom