# If I attempt to un-delete a question under a question ban, would it still be considered asking a new question?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

After using Stack Overflow for a while, I have a much better understanding of how things work. But while learning about the site, I made some very dumb mistakes.

Whenever a question I asked got down-voted, even once, I'd instantly delete my question, hoping the down-votes would just go away. I naively assumed they did when my reputation was restored. After about [three or four deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/6640099) I finally learned that deleting questions was a bad idea. I have decided to try to modify and un-delete these questions, to make them better received.

The only question that I don't know if I could fix is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642958/why-are-pointers-used-in-c). I deleted the question after receiving down-votes on it (not knowing what else to do, and thinking that that would fix everything), but not before it was closed.

After asking such poorly received questions, I was put on a question ban.

While I'm really not concerned about getting the privilege to ask questions again (as I think I learn more solving my own problems now), I would like to fix these questions. But I don't know if I'll be able to. The main questions I have are:

1. Since I'm under a question ban and my questions have been dormant for so long, would trying to modify and un-delete these questions be considered 'cheating the system', and I'd prohibited from doing so?
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642958/why-are-pointers-used-in-c), was by far the worst one. If i was going to vigorously remodel this question, such that the topic might be changed slightly, would it be considered as trying to ask a new question, instead of editing one?

Comment: Correcting/improving then undeleting questions? Good, if there really *is* a question hiding in there. Completely changing the meaning of a question (deleted or otherwise)? Probably not a good idea. Start by reading [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: @PaulRoub Take my _why are pointers used in c++_ question as an example. I was going to change it so that it is still about pointers per se, but not about why pointers are used.

Comment: be careful if you are going to try [Drastic Question Revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260069/839601)

Comment: @gnat Is there any place I could post my revised question to have it reviewed. I pretty sure that no place like that exit, but I might as well ask.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry http://chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You seem to show a great effort towards getting out of the question ban... are you unbanned yet?

Comment: @dorukayhan well I'm trying my best. But alas, I'm still banned. I think I'll just have to wait six months to get my chance to redeem myself. And, I think I'll ask SE to disassociate one of my worst questions from my account. Cheers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. > Since I'm under a question ban and my questions have been dormant for so long, would trying to modify and un-delete these questions be considered 'cheating the system', and I'd prohibited from doing so?

   As long as you're not changing the essence of the existing question to something else entirely, this is fine. The question was around to begin with; now you're just bringing it back from the dead and improving it (hopefully).
2. > This question, was by far the worst one. If i was going to vigorously remodel this question, such that the topic might be changed slightly, would it be considered as trying to ask a new question, instead of editing one?

   Yeah you'll have to be very careful — if the slightly different topic was the question you *meant* to ask and isn't all that different in essence from the original, that would be fine too, since nobody complains when a question gets closed as unclear and you clarify it and it turns out to be something quite different, while answerable.

   Most people will be able to spot attempts at completely tearing down old questions and replacing them with new ones via edits; if you're not doing that, you should be fine, but it doesn't hurt to be careful anyway.

   Put it this way: would you have posted your new question using the Ask page were you not blocked from posting questions? Was the Ask page the *first* destination that came to mind when you decided to post your question, assuming you didn't know or remember that you were blocked before? If not, you're probably fine.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I can go ahead and revise and un-delete the other questions that i deleted. But the one with 5 down-votes, i might just leave deleted. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: By the way, are you related to Bolt'sClock 'O Unicorn?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry If you mean "BoltClock's a Unicorn", that's [his account on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn).