How should I regain the privilege to ask questions when the very core of some of my downvoted questions deserve to be downvoted?
Let's say, theoretically of course ;), that I ask an utterly horrible question. (Or I ask an entirely valid question on meta, but people just don't like it. Either scenario works.) So horrible, in fact, that SO subsequently bans me from asking questions because I now have a bad question contribution record. Well, I can't ask new questions to balance it out, deleting the question won't help, and I can't edit the question to make it better unless I change it entirely.
Can I just edit the question so that it is an entirely new question and hopefully regain some of the votes?
What am I supposed to do in that situation?
Note: Questions like these these do not answer my questions. I might have misread, but they only tell me to edit my question so that it is better. My question is: if the question cannot be edited to appease the community, can I change the question an entirely different one?

if you were (theoretically, of course,) question banned for asking poor quality questions, you'd still be able to ask one question every 6 months.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

I do not think that these answer my questions. I might have misread, but it only tells me to edit my question so that it is better. My question is: if the question cannot be edited to appease the community, can I change the question an entirely different one.

No, don't change an existing question completely, but that's already covered as a totally different discussion - since you shouldn't do that regardless of motivation. Anyway, there really isn't anything you can do except to make your next question, 6 months from now, good enough to lift the ban. I agree this is a terrible design, but anything past this point is feature-request territory (and really belongs on the SE-wide meta), not discussion.

btw, do meta questions affect the question ban? if you look at my meta profile, I have a whole lot of questions with more than 10 downvotes. is that part of my problem?

No, they don't. Meta counts as a different site, so a ban here wouldn't affect main. That said, meta.SO (and possibly all child metas) do not have question bans at all, so you also can't get Q-banned from meta.SO at all

Ask 1 question. The link I gave answers one in the title & the one at the end. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260066/drastic-question-revision https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users Comments are not for asking new questions.

Addendum: on Meta downvotes have evolved to also include, "While your question is good and well-thought-out, I strongly disagree with the premise. No. We should emphatically NOT go what you propose."

“Well, I can't ask new questions to balance it out” - You absolutely can, one question every 6 months, repeat that process until you prove the 6 month rate limit is no longer required. In the end only contributing positively to the community will lift the question ban. There is no other way.

“can I change the question an entirely different one.” - You can but the community will roll back the question, since this is one way, to bypass a question ban. You were theoretically warned your questions were not being well received before you were theoretically question banned

You may be able to remove any association between you and your bad questions, by using the contact form. Because they're unsalvageable, they're just a burden. But I'm not sure whether that would count as evading the question ban.

Losing the privilege to ask questions is not a punishment; it is a protection mechanism to protect the knowledge base from more unwanted content. That really ups how deep the hole is that you're in when you reach that point. It is not about "how can I regain the ability to ask questions again", it is more "How can I make the system trust me to make correct decisions again".

@Lino - Disassociation of a user with a question is rarely done when a user is question banned. Author likely has numerous questions contributing to the question ban, one or two questions being disassociated from their profile, likely will NOT be enough to lift the question ban.

Meta posts have no effect on question bans on the main site.

You can ask one question per 6 months. Eventually, if your new 6-month-apart questions are positively received, in aggregate, more than your previous questions were negatively received, in aggregate, then the automatic question suspension will be lifted by the system.

@TylerH tries to say that a downvoted, closed, deleted question counts as -3, while a not downvoted, not closed and not deleted question counts as +1. You need a positive sum. In his world view, this is what he understands on "more positively received".

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Well I actually got some question ban for my meta activity :-)

@peterh You don't get question banned on Meta, nor does Meta activity induce a question ban--question bans are always automatically imposed by the system. As for your other comment, I'm not sure what you mean by 'my world view'; this is the way the system is; it's not a matter of perspective whatsoever.
